# OpenCV Native Camera View on Android 5.0 not working

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working on Android OpenCV based application. I am not able to run NativeCameraView on my MotoG after 5.0 lollipop update. The JavaCameraView is still working.

In my program I need to use VideoCapture (http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/index.html?org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture.html) in my program. I dont know how do I switch to JavaCameraView Source in VideoCapture. [Only NativeCamera works fine for my Application. Using JavaCameraView is just a temporary workaround which I am looking for]

So my question is, Is this a bug on OpenCV to fix the Native Camera for 5.0 ? I did not find anybody raising such an issue. When will this be fixed ?

02-06 13:30:52.794: E/OpenCV::camera(31745): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library
02-06 13:30:52.794: E/OpenCV::camera(31745): Native_camera returned opening error: 4

Comment: @I am Okay You are okay Im also getting this on lollipop

Comment: Camera is not available (in use or does not exist): Fail to connect to camera service,

Camera #0failed to open: Fail to connect to camera service

callback on dead camera object

Comment: Yes. The latest Android SDK from OpenCV is on 2014-10-02 (Version 2.4.10) . My guess is they are yet to support the Native CameraView or VideoCapture for lollipop. The workaround is you can use JavaCameraView in your application

Answer (score -1):

Problem is realted to permission. Copy following code into onCreate() method. Issue will get solve.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
}
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.